# Can the Getis-Ord Statistic really be considered a measure of spatial autocorrelation?

Tags: spatial-statistics, measurements, autocorrelation

The Getis-Ord statisic

G_i(*)= \Sigma_j w_{ij} x_j / \Sigma_j x_j

basically calculates a geographically weighted average at some point. Is it fair to say that it is rather a measure of spatial clustering or spatial heterogeneity than a measure of spatial autocorrelation?

Comment: Is this your homework? What are your thoughts pro and contra your statement?

Comment: No homework, just thoughts. Pro autocorrelation: Literature, contra autocorrelation: No interactions in specification.